Access dynamically to CrudRepository
Sorry for the low example of code I could share but my project is a job project, and also sorry for my english that could contain error :D
Here's my problem I got several Entity and Repository in my service (up to 50 entity - repo)
I have to implement a manager that will be called by user.
The data coming from a CSV file that contain all the the line for each entity defined as :
trigram_1;col_1;col_2
trigram_2;col_1;col_2;col_3
(the size of the line column can change for each trigram)
The generation of my entity with the csv file is good, and works fine with reflection and introspection
I also set in my manager a way to get the entity populated depending on which trigram I give.
for this i use Reflection on package with that kind of implementation :
public Map<String,Class> findAllClassesUsingReflectionsLibrary(String packageName) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false));
    return reflections.getSubTypesOf(MySuperEntity.class)
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Class::SimpleName, obj -> obj));
}

public foo(String trigram, String data){
    // this is only an example of usage
    Map<String,Class> map = findAllClassesUsingReflectionsLibrary("path.to.package.entity");
    String key = "prefix"+trigram+"Db";
    if(map.contains(key)){
        MySuperEntity entity = map.get(key).newInstance().instantiate(data)
        // instantiate is a method defined by my MySuperEntity superclass 
        // that create an instance of the class and add the data to each attribute
        //
    } 
    //....
}

it works perfectly for entity, but now my problem is to do the "same" for repository
My problem here is that repository types are CrudRepository and I'm not able to get access to their implementation by doing reflection on the package where they are stored (cause they are interface and aren't instatiable by myself).
Initially they was added in the constructor and Spring/hibernate deal by themself to build it correctly but I won't follow this initial implementation that push me to just doing a stupid switch for 50 trigram...
public CrudRepository getRepo(String trigram){
    switch(trigram){
        case "AAA" :
            return repositoryAAA;
        break;
        case "BBB" : 
            // ...
    }
}

So is there a way to access in my repository implementation? (without implementing by myself instead of doing an interface)
I actually tried to find some documentation about this but i found nothing (maybe i didn't search in the good way?)
i tried to get the repository by this method without really care if they are interface but it doesn't work.

with many research and test I found a solution so I post it for the next
I decided to use Spring ApplicationContext to get access to the bean and create a superClass as an interface for each of my concerned repository to filter them and don't get every repository that my project have.
as a code it's pretty easy :
public class MyManager{
    private Map<String, SraRepository> mappedRepo;

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    public MyManager(ApplicationContext context){
        this.context=context;
        this.mappedRepo=context.getBeansOfType(MyRepoSuperInterface.class);
    }
 
    public foo(String repoName){
        MyRepoSuperInterface repo;
        if(mappedRepo.containsKey(repoName){
            repo = mappedRepo.get(repoName);
        }
        // doSomething with the repo
    }
}

Bye!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
